# async.js Ordering of functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

So I'm having trouble getting one *javascript* function to finish before the next one starting. I've spent quite a lot of time trying to use callback methods described on other stackoverflow posts. I could get simple examples that used timeouts to work but couldn't get it to work with my API request. I stumbled upon `async.js` and thought that perhaps using `async.series` would be a good idea to get my two functions to perform one after another. So I tried this approach, however I still seem to be having the problem where the first function takes a bit longer to execute (which is fine) but the execution process moves past this function instead of waiting for it to end. I feel I have a misconception of some sort since I have tried several methods but to no avail.

What is strange is, is that that when running `server.js`, it goes into the first function but then it leaves the `async.series()` function even before the request is finished. When I print inside of `tokenReq()`, I can see that the request was successful as a token code is returned successfully however this happens to late as execution has moved on. The output is shown below.

server.js:

```
var access_code;
async.series([
    function() {
        access_code = queries.data.tokenReq(code);
        console.log("Finished inside function 1");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("\n Starting function 2 \n");

        if (access_code === "error") {
            res.json("An error has occured");
        } else {
            var response = queries.data.messagesReq(access_code);
            res.json(response);
        }
    }
],
function(err, access_code) {
});

console.log("Outside");
```

queries.js:

```
tokenReq: function(code) {
    var tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var form = {
        code: code,
        client_id: "__ID__",
        redirect_uri: "__Site__/",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_secret: "__Secret__",
    };


    var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
    var contentLength = formData.length;

    request({
            headers: {
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            uri: tokenUrl,
            body: formData,
            method: 'POST'
        }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error != "null") {
            var access_token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
            console.log("\n INSIDE FUNCTION REQUEST, Token: " + access_token + " \n");
            return access_token;

        } else {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            //   console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            return "error";
        }
    });
},
```

Output:

```
Finished inside function 1
Outside

INSIDE FUNCTION REQUEST, Token: 8Swhd.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a major point here. Since node.js is asynchronous there should not be a way to know when a function completes its execution. That is why we specify callbacks so that the invoking function knows whom to call when it finishes its execution. Once you have functions with callbacks, you can enforce series/parallel/waterfall behavior with `async` module.

```
tokenReq: function(code, cb) {
    var tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var form = {
        code: code,
        client_id: "__ID__",
        redirect_uri: "__Site__/",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_secret: "__Secret__",
    };


    var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
    var contentLength = formData.length;

    request({
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        uri: tokenUrl,
        body: formData,
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error != "null") {
            var access_token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
            console.log("\n INSIDE FUNCTION REQUEST, Token: " + access_token + " \n");
            return cb(null, access_token);

        } else {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            //   console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            return cb(new Error("whatever"));
        }
    });
},
```

Now, you can use the callback inside `server.js`

```
var access_code;
async.series([
    function(cb) {
        return queries.data.tokenReq(code, cb);
    },
    function(access_code, cb) {
        console.log("\n Starting function 2 \n");

        if (access_code === "error") {
            res.json("An error has occured");
        } else {
            var response = queries.data.messagesReq(access_code);
            res.json(response);
        }
        // do whatever you want after this
        return cb();
    }
],
function(err, access_code) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    // wrap your logic around a function and call the correspoding callback here
});
```